# storing arrays of string literals without size - simple template over array size

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, literals

I am exploring methods for storing arrays of literals (any type) without sidecar size information. I've sketched some approaches but for each have some lingering questions.  This is the simplest method, a template over array size. Please note that this is a simple test case and that actual classes might have additional members, additional template parameters, and template parameters that must be provided.

```
template <size_t I>
struct A0 {
    std::array<const char*, I> a;
};
```

The problem is that the size is detached from the string literals, making these sort of errors too easy:

```
// error, not caught
auto a0 = A0<3>{{"1","2"}};
```

While the following intialization is valid, because C++20 does not allow partial CTAD it cannot work if any template argument *must* be specified. Also it trades boilerplate for boilerplate: '<3>' in exchange for 'std::array'. Without specifying the type CTAD won't be able to deduce the template size parameter 'I'.

```
auto a0 = A0{std::array{"1","2"}};
```

Is there a deduction guide that allows:

```
auto a0 = A0{{"1","2"}};
```

Comment: better edit the original question. Or at least delete the old one

Comment: You might use regular constructor if you want some control and (disable some behavior from aggregate initialization).

Answer (score 0):

So, you are asking about `auto a0 = A0{{"1","2"}};`, but first here is a deduction guide for `auto a0 = A0{"1","2"};`:

```
template<typename... Ts>
A0(Ts...) -> A0<sizeof...(Ts)>;
```

I think it is clear what it does. It simply counts the number of arguments given.

For `auto a0 = A0{{"1","2"}};`:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
A0(const T(&)[N]) -> A0<N>;
```

This relies on the fact that a braced argument can be deduced to an array type by template argument deduction. The caveat here is that all the elements of the braced argument must have the same type.

If you want to use both of the deduction guides, you should constrain `T` in the second one not to be `const char` to make sure that the special case `A0{"123"}` is not considered as array case. You might want to constrain the types anyway depending on what implicit conversions you want to allow in this form.

Both of these then, after the class template argument deduction, rely on aggregate initialization (the additional braces can be left out) to actually construct the class instance. But if you have constructors in the class instead, it will work the same.

Comment: How is a deduction guide concerning the default constructor which is skipped during aggregate initialization, able to influence aggregate initialization?

Comment: @user19087 I am not sure what you mean with "a deduction guide concerning the default constructor". There is a default constructor (implicitly) and it has a corresponding deduction guide, but that deduction guide is useless since it can't deduce `I`. But neither deduction guides nor implicit default constructors have anything to do with aggregate initialization. The initialization choice is made only after the type has been deduced via CTAD and is independent of it. (CTAD does not decide the constructor to use or whether it will be aggregate initialization)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template constructor that that combined with a user defined deduction guidline either deduces the correct argument count or results in a compiler error, if the user specifies the incorrect number of parameters:

```
template <size_t I>
struct A0 {
    template<class ...Args>
    constexpr A0(Args...args)
        : a{ args... }
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == I, "parameter count does not match array size");
    }

    std::array<const char*, I> a;
};

template<class ...Args>
A0(Args...) -> A0<sizeof...(Args)>;

constexpr A0 a{ "1", "2", "3" };
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<decltype(a)>, A0<3>>, "expectation mismatch");

constexpr A0<4> a1 { "1", "2", "3" }; // compiler error: parameter count does not match array size
```